# IEEE 754 exponent and cohort

Tags: ieee-754, representation

I'm wonder if in the IEEE 754 norm, their is anything to avoid cohort.

Does the norm implies to have the lesser exponent as possible or not? Or cohort are present?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Representation_and_encoding_in_memory): When a result can have several representations, the standard specifies which member of the cohort is chosen.

Comment: @Barmar : How did I miss this? Thank you very much for the quick answer